# Two if statements in the update controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I have a controller with update method.

```
def update
 @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
 @lesson = @student.lessons.find(params[:id])

 @lesson.update_attributes(lesson_params)
 redirect_to @lesson.student, notice: "Les updated"
end
```

That works just fine!. 
I want to add new if statement that change the :paid params from false to true. so I put it like this

```
 def update
    @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
    @lesson = @student.lessons.find(params[:id])

    @lesson.update_attributes(lesson_params)
    redirect_to @lesson.student, notice: "Les updated"

    if @lesson.paid == nil
      @lesson.paid = true
      @lesson.save
      redirect_to @lesson.student, notice:"Les is betaald!"
    end
  end
```

When I click the button in the view to change the :paid param I get this error

```
param is missing or the value is empty: lesson
```

If I make it like this

```
def update
 if @lesson.paid == nil
   @lesson.paid = true
   @lesson.save
   redirect_to @lesson.student, notice:"Les is betaald!"
 end
end
```

It works fine!
So for now, it looks like that I can use only one if statement!
I tried to use elsif, but it doesn't help!

The params

```
private
  def lesson_params
    params.require(:lesson).permit(:date, :time, :paid)
  end
```

The code of the view to update :paid params

```
<% if les.paid === nil %>
   <td><%= link_to "Niet betaald", [@student, les, paid: true], method: :put, class: "niet-betaald" %>
   </td>
    <% else %>
   <td style="color:lightgrey;">Betaald</td>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ don’t use triple-equal in ruby unless you understand what is does. Also, to check a value for being `nil` use `nil?` method: `if les.paid.nil?`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks. I'll change it. But that not solving my problem.

Comment: You have a redirect being called before the conditional block, which is going to end execution, the if statement will never run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your update method to this:

```
def update
  @student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  @lesson = @student.lessons.find(params[:id])

  if @lesson.paid.nil?
    lesson_params[:paid] = true
    notice = 'Les is betaald!'
  else
    notice = 'Les updated'
  end

  @lesson.update_attributes(lesson_params)
  redirect_to @lesson.student, notice: notice
end
```

One of the issues is that you're calling a redirect_to before the if block, which will end the execution of the method (it's essentially calling return and then proceeding to render the view). You're also calling update_attributes, and then potentially calling save, which is going to make 2 calls to the database, you can simply update the param value and only update the attributes once, which is a little more efficient.

Comment: Just looked again, I think because there is no definition of lesson in the link, maybe try something like [@student, les, lesson: { paid: true }]